# Наследование селектора

Tags: css

Применяю этот селектор в надежде, что он будет действовать только на строки в таблице класса main-view. Но стиль автоматически наследуется на другие бесклассовые таблицы. Есть слабые подозрения на blueprint.css, но думаю дело не в нем. Не подскажете в чем дело?

```
table.main-view tr:hover
```

Comment: по тестировал на чистой странице, работает так как и должно. скорей всего blueprint.css, либо другие загружаемые стили

Comment: Блин извиняюсь, что не протестировал. Наверное, получается где-то прописан для таблицы inherit?

Comment: Попробуйте !important

Comment: не пробуйте импортант, ищите причину

Comment: Да это работает, но на каждые свойства !important прописывать как-то не айс.

Comment: Попытка не пытка, вдруг там js подключает стили : ) и конечно согласен нужно искать причину.

Comment: Еще одно дополнение у меня таблица в таблице. Возможно все дело в селекторе и он автоматически ищет все tr необращая внимания на то, что вложенная таблица имеет уже другой класс.

Comment: @dogmar нет проект мой и там есть только jquery и стили им не применял.

Answer (score 2):

Если таблицы лежат внутри table.main-view, то все ясно: tr этих таблиц также лежат внутри table.main-view, поэтому правило применяется и к ним. Пропишите `table.main-view > tbody > tr:hover`.

**Исправлено**

Comment: Попробовал, но увы все равно вложенная таблица подхватывает стиль

Comment: Все работает надо просто выбрать прямых потомков table > tbody. Рабочий вариант: table.main-view > tbody > tr:hover. Спасибо всем!

Comment: Да, спасибо). Вечно с этим моментом косячу.